# Three threads one for input from keyboard second for encryption and third to print the input

Tags: operating-system, mutex

I have to make three threads T1,T2,T3. T1 should take input from keyboard as a string.T2 should encrypt the input. T3 should print the string. So the problem is to serialize threads T1,T2 and T3. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t inp,encr,prnt;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;; 
sem_t sem;
char input_string[30];

void Input(void *ar){

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",input_string);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}

void Encrypt(void* ar){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    input_string[0]='a';
    input_string[1]='b';
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}   

void Print(void *ar){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("%s\n",input_string );
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   // sleep(1000);

}    



int main(){
    sem_init(&sem,0,1);
    pthread_create( &inp, NULL, Input, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_create( &encr, NULL, Encrypt, (void*)NULL);
    pthread_create( &prnt, NULL, Print, (void*)NULL);
//while(1){
    pthread_join(inp,NULL);
    //sleep(3000);
    pthread_join(encr,NULL);
    //sleep(4000);
    pthread_join(prnt,NULL);
  //  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained the problem you're having with the code you've posted or asked a question of any form. (It's also unclear how the "operating system" tag applies here.)

Comment: Serialize threads?  Pointless. Serializing the management of data between them, often desirable.  That's what producer-consumer queues are for.

Comment: I am sorry. The problem is i wanted to serialize the threads but was unable to do so.But I solved it now.anyway thank you.